# iOS 16.1.1 runtime error: RB query for the extension process state failed

Tags: swift, keyboard, ios16

I am working on a project and getting a runtime error when running our app on some colleague's iPhone 11 device(iOS 16.1.1) :

```
[lifecycle] [u 68C8D161-6D2A-412E-A4F2-CEDE8D1C83EF:m (null)] 
[*PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER(MARKETING_VERSION)*] RB query for the extension process state failed with error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 
"Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}
```

The [*PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER(MARKETING_VERSION)*] is something like : com.companyName.AppName.Keyboard(1.0.10)

This error message is only appears when the customized keyboard is loaded,
and the keyboard is also part of app group

I've checked iOS16 release note, seems like nothing is relevant to this error, I'm not sure what is causing this error message?

Answer (score 2):

So I got this issue while developing an app with Flutter, the keyboard (Google keyboard) tries to pop up but it fails. If you're like me and you need a solution, I got this error while using a Form with textfields, but I was initializing the form key inside my build method and I was using a StatelessWidget so I had to switch to a StatefulWidget and place the form key outside the build method. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I fix this issue by rebuilding

Answer (score 2):

I believe this problem is related to AutofillGroup. It's definitely a bug. We have experienced this in the wild with our app, randomly, for months, but finally it happened on one of our own test devices. All sorts of changes seem to mitigate the problem, but none of them make sense, for example, scrolling the text field slightly off screen can allow the keyboard to appear, adding a SizedBox of height 200 in the middle of the screen can fix it, removing widgets, adding them, but that's all inconsistent and unhelpful, the only consistent way we've found so far to fix it, is removing AutoFillGroup. Will update if we get more info.

Comment: Thx for reply and sharing your experience, resources of making custom keyboard is pretty minority, and indeed this is a randomly issue, hope it could be solved in iOS16.5 ( or at least no need to fix again).

Comment: I think we have solved this problem now. In our case, we had a screen, which contained a ListView of various widgets, various text fields, for example, username at the top, email/password at the bottom. The email and password widgets were part of another widget. The AutoFillGroup was within this widget. By removing it from there, and moving it into the parent, everything now seems to be fine!

Comment: @leon Just to calrify, we didnt use a custom keyboard. Most searches on Google about this bug highlight the Google keyboard, GBOARD, but we were able to confirm it applied to all keyboards, including the Apple keyboard, the reason why everyone is discussing Gboard is because only Gboard actually prints out an error to the log .. Apple keyboard remains silent

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the custom keyboard UI by the old one, not even modify my code, reinstall the app and our custom keyboard and somehow it just worked.

2024 updated:
To anyone who got this or similar issue, make sure you've solve ALL auto layout warning first.

Regarding to [Apple's user experience of keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html):
—it’s fast, responsive, and capable.

System will kill your custom keyboard if it taking too much time to load and replace with a system default keyboard, so you also need to minimize loading time of your custom keyboard, avoid doing some heavy preparation when keyboard is loading.

Answer (score 0):

I did run in the same error and since re-installing helped, I'm pretty sure that this has to to with the keyboards "Allow Full Access" ability.

As soon as you run a new version with changed code, the "Full Access" check fails with this error.
I think that this error would never show up for customers, only during development.

Comment: I've update my dev environment to Xcode15.2 and MacOS 13.6.4, tested on iOS 15.6.1 device.

The issue never happened since I simplify custom keyboard's UI hierarchy.
Still, I modify some code to test your presumptions, it seems like modified code won't affect keyboard full access setting.